# Redirect location includes ":80" when X-Forwarded-Proto is https

Tags: grails, nginx, asset-pipeline, grails-3.0

Nginx terminates SSL for our app, communication between Nginx and app servers happens on port 8080, our app had no `grails.serverURL` set in config.

We had a regular redirect:

```
redirect uri: '/login'
```

But when accessed via HTTPS the redirect returned:

```
Location: https://domain.com:80/login
```

As a result browsers attempt to open SSL connections over port 80 and fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header from `nginx.conf` or adding `X-Forwarded-Port` (**recommended**) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Adding either of the following worked for me:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
```

or

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
```